# Eclipse flags a piece of code with a 'Dead code' warning. Why in this case?

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

I know that there are a few examples of 'random dead code warning' in Eclipse.

But specifically for my case, I want to find out whether this is also a 'false positive' or whether I am too tired to understand what is going on...

```
    @Override
    public int getNumUnappendedCol() {

        return appendIndex == -1 ? getNumCol() : appendIndex; 
    }
```

This ternary statement is being flagged, specifically the condition and `appendIndex`. As I understand it (not my code), this is supposed to return `appendIndex` if it is *not* equal to -1. Otherwise return the value obtained from `getNumCol()`.

Am I missing something or should I just ignore Eclipse? I regularly refresh/ clean/ build the project so that wouldn't solve the issue.

Comment: Is there something in your class (such as a `final` declaration maybe) that either prevents `appendIndex` from being `-1` or compels it to be `-1`?

Comment: @DavidWallace Too much PHP recently! Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @DavidWallace That's it. appendIndex was indeed declared as final and set to -1. Thanks for the tip. I would gladly accept your solution if you'd post one besides your comment.

Comment: @ChrisKeil You can post it yourself and do a self-accept if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being a `final` declaration of `appendIndex` which was initialized to -1, so the ternary statement could never even access the false option.